# Разделить и вычесть число из нескольких других

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Что-то не могу придумать, как правильно реализовать.

Есть число, скажем

```
$a = 300;
```

Есть массив (элементов может быть минимум 1 и максимум - много)

```
$b = array(
    50,
    570,
    2400,
);
```

Нужно придумать два варианта вычитания

1 - если есть в массиве число большое из которого можно сразу вычесть $a, то делать это.
2 - если нет большого числа, то разделить $a и списать с каждого элемента в массиве, но так, чтобы элемент не ушел в 0.

Грубо-говоря, чтобы было понятно, $a - это скидка на товары. Нужно ее разделить между ценами товаров, чтобы скидка отнялась либо у самого дорого товара, либо у всех по немного. Главное, не уводить цены товара в 0.

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении задачи!)

Comment: Неужели первый вариант не получается?

Comment: @drop_off разделить $a на что?

Comment: @MBo Первый не проблема. Дело в том, чтобы предусмотреть вариант, когда все "цены" будут примерно одинаковы и чтобы тупо с самобого большого не списать почти все. Типа, чтобы частично с каждого списывало.

Comment: @Эдуард как вариант на количество "товаров" которые есть в $b

Comment: @drop_off а значение `$a = 300;` в каких диапазонах может колебаться? Дело в том, что при таком подходе все значения массива могут уходить в минус.

Comment: @Эдуард в минус не уйдет. Сумма в массиве всегда будет больше на 50-70%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

Посчитать сумму всех элементов S

Если скидка a меньше S, то раскидать её по всем элементам пропорционально их значениям

```
b[i] = b[i] - a * b[i] / S
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/dip2kv)  (если нужны целые - значения нужно округлять и накапливать ошибку)

```
$a = 300;

$b = array(
    50,
    570,
    2400,
);

$s = array_sum($b);
if ($s > $a) {
    $ratio = 1 - $a / $s;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++) {
        $b[$i] *= $ratio;
    }
}

var_dump( $b, $s, $ratio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, если я все правильно понял:

```
<?php

function f (array $prices, int $discount) {

    $prices_more_than_discount = array_filter ($prices, function ($price) use ($discount) {

        return $price > $discount;
    });

    if (count ($prices_more_than_discount) > 0) {

        $prices [array_search (max ($prices_more_than_discount), $prices)] -= $discount;
    }
    else {

        $sum_of_prices = array_sum ($prices);

        if ($sum_of_prices > $discount) {

            $new_discount = 1 - $discount / $sum_of_prices;
            $prices = array_reduce ($prices, function ($new_prices, $price) use ($new_discount) {

                $new_prices [] = $price * $new_discount;
                return $new_prices;
            }, []);
        }
    }

    return $prices;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> *Сумма в массиве всегда будет больше на 50-70%*

```
$max = max($b);

if ($max > $a) {
    $k = array_keys($b, $max)[0];
    $b[$k] = $b[$k] - $a;
} else {
    $a = $a / count($b);
    $b = array_map(function($i)use($a){
        return $i - $a;
    }, $b);
}

var_dump( $b );
```

Comment: Для второго случая, после вычитания - возможно появление значений <=0